# What is the cleanest, most transparent way to rapidly excite a resonant bandpass to a given amplitude (for musical synthesis)?

Tags: filters, audio, frequency-spectrum, bandpass, resonance

## Background

Music audio synthesis can be performed using underdamped resonant bandpasses as harmonic oscillators (set to harmonic frequencies of a given note). These can then be excited when input signals are run through them.

The common ways for exciting such an array of harmonic bandpasses would be: dirac impulses; some type of envelope signal, typically going from 0 to a max amplitude (say 1), then back to 0; and noise bursts (ie. noise signal multiplied by an envelope signal).

I am mostly interested in using envelopes as I believe they are the correct solution for what I want, but I will review the other points just for background.

### 1) Dirac

I have found Dirac impulses not very good (if conceived as a single unit sample at a given amplitude) because I believe the power of the signal varies with sample rates. At high sample rates, the impulse is very skinny, and at low sample rates it becomes fatter, which makes it not reliable. I believe this is true at least. Last time I checked was years ago but they were simply not useful which I believed was due to this.

### 2) Noise bursts

Noise bursts certainly are valuable but contribute a lot of "sound." If using random noise, they create random excitations, which can be good or bad, and how you shape the noise via envelope or filtering is subjective.

### 3) Envelopes

I have experimented with anything from sine/cosine waves to ADSR (attack-decay-sustain-release) to discontinuity type envelopes (I will just call all these "envelopes" to be simple). This is what I am interested in using.

## My Ideas

My goal is to cleanly and quickly (with as little character) excite a bandpass to a given amplitude (measured at at its $f_0$), and then let it decay naturally at its Q after that. There should be few or no random artefacts.

### 1) Controlled Discontinuities

My first idea is to feed in an envelope signal that increases slowly from 0 to a max amplitude (say 1) at a rate that is inaudible in typical audio frequency ranges, then let it drop back to 0 in an immediate discontinuity.

I believe such a discontinuity creates a burst (click) across the entire frequency spectrum which is flat across all frequencies and reliable in amplitude. Is this correct? If so, does the amplitude of the output at each frequency match the amplitude of the signal before it goes to 0 (ie. 1)? Or how is the frequency response of the "click" scaled relative to the amplitude?

I also believe that because the bandpass only has a memory of two samples prior, as long as you hold the input signal at the maximum level for at least a few samples regardless of sample rate, the subsequent discontinuity will have an equal effect across sample rates. Correct?

Lastly, I believe one could also do this in reverse for the same effect - have a signal that immediately goes from 0 to 1, and then gradually declines at a rate too slow to hear.

**Example 1:**
For example, I suspect one could start a 20 hz cosine wave shifted to zero baseline as `exciter = 0.5 * (-cosWave20Hz + 1)` for 1/2 period to amplitude 1 and then drop it to zero, and this would be a "silent" way of then getting an even excitation across the spectrum.

**Example 2:**
A similar idea but perhaps better would be to create a critically damped oscillator at say 20 Hz. Then you could create a discontinuity by starting it at say amplitude of 1 immediately from 0 and then letting it decline to 0 from there at the critically damped rate which should be inaudible and not significantly affect the bandpasses on decay.

### 2) Matched Frequency Sine Waves

The other way I have theorized one might be able to "cleanly" or reliably excite bandpasses to a given amplitude would be to run sine waves matched to the frequencies of the bandpasses through them.

For example, if you have a 80 hz bandpass, you could run a 80 hz sine wave through it, but I am not sure how to do this without a clicking discontinuity at the start. You could use an envelope to shape the excitation signal, but the peak excitation of the bandpass I think becomes difficult to predict this way as it depends on how many oscillations you feed in and how you enveloped it.

## Question

What do you think? Do my thoughts make sense? I can create any of these with trial and error and have done so at varying times. But I would appreciate any theoretical guidance on what I am thinking as I am not well versed in DSP/signals or analyzing the output to seeing I'm achieving my goal.

I wonder if my understanding of "controlled discontinuities" is generally correct and what makes most sense for what I am trying to attain (ie. "silent" or reproducable excitation to a given amplitude of a given bandpass).

## Put simply...

Let's say you have a resonant bandpass set to Q and F. It is silent at amplitude 0 with 0 dB gain at its F. You want to reliably/quickly get it up to an amplitude of 1 (at its $f_0$) and then let it resonate in peace undisturbed.

What audio input signal do you pass through it to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would call them «parametric shaped pulse» rather than «envelopes» even if they share the same parameters. To me, «envelope» implies a low-bandwidth amplitude shaping of a high-bandwidth input signal

Comment: Don't excite the filter with an input signal. Set its internal state to what you want and let it decay. You can derive that internal state by looking at the state if excited with the filter's own resonance frequency for a sufficiently long duration.

Comment: Thanks Jazzmaniac, but needing to excite it regardless of its current state is part of the musical point. For example "plucking" a guitar string that is already in "motion" but putting another input impulse through it. So one needs a way to reliably attain a certain excitation, and one needs to be able to also do this on the fly (even if the excitation then becomes more random in less controlled conditions) while the bandpass is already resonating.

Comment: The internal state is also linear. You can just add to the internal state to excite in addition to what's already going on.